# Почему не вызывается событие

Tags: c#

Всем привет, есть такой вот код

```
using System;
class a
{
    public virtual event EventHandler MyEv;   
    public void StartEvent()
    {
        MyEv(4, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}
class b : a
{
    public override event EventHandler MyEv;
}
class c
{
    static void Main()
    {
        b B = new b();
        B.MyEv += (o, e) => Console.WriteLine("From class B");
        B.StartEvent();
    }
}
```

Почему не вызывается обработчик добавленный к типу `B`, ведь событие было переопределено в классе `B` ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Событие в C# это набор из:

- приватного поля-делегата
- метода add
- метода remove
- метаданных

Т.к. в C# (и вообще .NET) нет виртуальных полей, то `virtual` на `event` делает виртуальными только методы `add` / `remove`. Неявная реализация события приводит к тому, что классы `a` и `b` получают каждый свое приватное поле-делегат. И свою  пару `add`/`remove`, которая работает или с полем из `a` или с полем из `b`. Т.е. ваш код эквивалентен следующему:

```
class a
{
    private EventHandler _MyEvField;
    public virtual event EventHandler MyEv
    {
        add
        {
            _MyEvField += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _MyEvField -= value;
        }
    }

    public void StartEvent()
    {
        _MyEvField(4, EventArgs.Empty);
    }
}

class b : a
{
    private EventHandler _MyEvField_2;

    public override event EventHandler MyEv
    {
        add
        {
            _MyEvField_2 += value;
        }
        remove
        {
            _MyEvField_2 -= value;
        }
    }
}
```

т.е. override переопределяет механизм подписки на событие. Но не переопределяет поле, которе используется для вызова в `a.StartEvent`. При этом поле остается приватным, и добраться до него из класса `b` не получится. Чтобы все заработало, вам придется делать виртуальным еще и метод `StartEvent`, и переопределять его в `b`.

Это делает механизм virtual/override для событий полностью бессмысленным. Максимум, для чего его можно использовать - трассировка, логгирование или мокинг.

Comment: `получают каждый свое приватное поле-делегат` точно ! Спасибо. Этого момента я как раз и не учел.